# Compare angular copy and changed data in angularjs and send only changed items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an edit form.
Where I am getting a JSON as

```
$scope.allDeviceData= [];
```

and angular copy as

```
$scope.allDeviceDataCopy= [];
```

#### `allDeviceData` is:

```js
allDeviceData = [{
  "id": "31",
  "log_time": "7",
  "record_mode": "0",
  "upload_interval": "6",
  "sampling_time": "3",
  "log_method": "3",
  "ntp_setting": "0",
  "header1": "MyCloud0",
  "footer": "MyCloud",
  "autodownload": "0",
  "autoupdatetime": "0",
  "downloaded_time": null,
  "unit_id": "144",
  "userid": "19",
  "unit_name": "living window",
  "mac_id": "C20BFCFF9C44",
  "group_name": "testing",
  "mdlno": "Mmag",
  "battery_val": "0",
  "battery": {
    "id": "2604709",
    "battery_val": "3.3",
    "network_val": "-62",
    "updatetime": "2018-09-14 00:43:35 ",
    "unit_id": "144"
  },
  "channelinfo": [{
    "id": "5462236",
    "chkey": "ch1",
    "chvalue": "0",
    "updatetime": "2018-09-14 00:43:35 ",
    "unit_id": "144"
  }],
  "channels": [{
    "id": "59",
    "chkey": "ch1",
    "unit_id": "144",
    "input_type": "Magnetic",
    "unit": "unit",
    "decimal_value": "0",
    "offset_value": "0",
    "gain_value": "0",
    "range_low": "0",
    "range_high": "0",
    "high_name": "opened",
    "low_name": "0",
    "Condition_high": "0",
    "Condition_low": "0",
    "Threshold_high": "4",
    "Threshold_low": "0",
    "reset_low": "0",
    "reset_high": "0",
    "activate_high": "0",
    "activate_low": "0",
    "notify_high": "1",
    "notify_low": "0",
    "Judgtime_high": "4",
    "judgetime_low": "0",
    "tempchvalue": "0",
    "chtempvalue1": "0"
  }]
}]
```

I want to compare `allDeviceData` and `allDeviceDataCopy` and send only changed fields and remove others.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have sample data. it will help to understand the array structure.

Comment: Added sample data i.e allDeviceData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular.equals( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) to get whether the changed data is dirty or not.
If dirty then you can iterate and compare the values and get the changed values.